# How fix sticky footer in wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I want to use a sticky footer in wordpress. I tried a lot but it's not working How can I displayed footer at the bottom of page ? please suggest any wordpress plugin. This is my website url: http://f9interiors.com  I have to submit this project by end of the day. Please help me out of from this. Thank you.

```
#footer-wrapper {
    background: url(images/footerbg.jpg) repeat center top;
    position: relative;
    color: #2e5790;
    text-align: center;
}


.copyright-wrapper {
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 -2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
}

.copyright-wrapper .container{
   display: inline-block;
     text-align:center;
      padding:12px;
box-shadow:0 -2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
}
```

```
<div id="footer-wrapper">

        <div class="copyright-wrapper">
            <div class="container">            

               <?php esc_attr_e('F9 Architects & Interior Designers','');?> , <?php esc_attr_e('Madhapur, Hyderabad. Ph: +91-40-66664949 | Email: enquiry@fortune9.in', '');?><br/>
            </div>          
        </div>
    </div>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please modify the CSS file as given below.

```
#footer-wrapper {
background: url(images/footerbg.jpg) repeat center top;
position: fixed;
color: #2e5790;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;}

.copyright-wrapper {
background-color: white;
/* position: absolute; */
line-height: 15px;
width: 100%;
box-shadow: 0 -2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);}
```

Remove the "**position: absolute;**" attribute from "**.copyright-wrapper**" class.